# SQL Server 2012 - Data Migration to a database with modified schema

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, data-migration, redgate

We have a database in production running on SQL Server 2012,  the database was copied and then changes were made to the schema, structure, relationships during further development of our application that uses the database.

We are now ready to migrate the data from the old production database to our newly developed database.  We spent a late night last night trying to figure out how to get that done using Red Gate's SQL Schema Comare, and SQL Data Compare.  We were not very successful as kept getting errors during the SQL Schema Compare Deployment.

The options and features of Red Gate's tools are very extensive and I don't have much experience using them.  I tried creating migration scripts within SQL Compare, but as the databases weren't linked up to source control prior, I don't see where or how to write these scripts.

The question I have is what is the proper sequence to migrate data using Red Gate's tools,  or would it just be easier to create SSIS packages to handle it all.  The amount of records we are migrating is relatively low less than 10,000 records.  We would like to preserve the identity values as we have some scripts that may depend on the specific identity values.

Any tips, suggestions, and comments are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing treating this issue as an ETL process using SSIS may be the best approach.  If anyone has any other alternatives, let me know.  I'll keep this up for a bit longer to see if anyone bites.

Comment: Prod is running and app is using it. You've branched prod, call it Prod', made lots of object changes (tables, functions, procs, etc). Those changes also incorporated lookup/reference entries. Now, you want to make Prod' the proper prod instance and catch up all the data that's loaded into Prod since the branch? Did I accurately understand the scenario? The desire then of your question is how best to guide the data?

Comment: Yes that pretty much sums up my situation.

Comment: "we have some scripts that may depend on the specific identity values" - this sounds like a very risky design and should probably be revisited.

Comment: I would go with SSIS - it will give you control over the sequence of migration events which is often critical.  This is not a trivial task and should be looked at as a mini-application in its own right.

Comment: Unfortunately the database was already poorly designed,  but it's what I have to work with now until we can allot time to optimize the design.  I was able to migrate the static data over using Red Gate's Data Compare,  but I will use SSIS for the transaction tables.